# Failing to retrieve information from text file java

Tags: java, function, methods, ide, logic

I have created a very simple java program (I am only a beginner) that involves data from an array being stored in a text file at the end of the program; this works fine. I am experiencing issues when the program is run again. It should retrieve all the data but doesn't. I have tested it using: `System.out.println("test");` The function I am using seems to be starting and the text file has the correct data.

Here is the function:

```
  public static void getArrayData(String [][] array){


      try {
         Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("arrayData.txt"));

         System.out.println(array.length);

         for(int i=0; i<array.length;  i++)
         {
            for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++)
            {
              System.out.println("Test 1");
              System.out.println(array[i][j]);

              if ( ! scan2.hasNext() )  //if there's nothing left to read
                  return; 

               array[i][j]=scan2.next(); 

            }  
         }


      } 

      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
         { 
         System.out.println("Test 2");
         e.printStackTrace(); 
         }    

   }
```

All the function seems to be returning is test null test null test null. Obviously this is not what I want.

I am new to programming so I apologise for the most probably simple issue or stupid mistake. Any help or tips are welcome. If you need any more information please don't hesitate to ask.

Many thanks in advance

Here is the full code:

```
 import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class simpleAI2
{

   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      int count = 0;
      String[][] array = new String [20][4];
      simpleAI2.getArrayData(array);
      String leaveQ;
      int rep = 1;

      do
      {
         int countTwo = 0;
         boolean flag = false;
         Scanner scanName = new Scanner (System.in);
         Scanner scanSport = new Scanner (System.in);
         Scanner leave = new Scanner (System.in);


         System.out.println("My name is A.I.S.C.M.B.T. What is your name?");
         array[count][1] = scanName.nextLine ();
         System.out.println("Hi "+array[count][1]+"! What's your favourite sport?");
         array[count][2] = scanSport.nextLine ();
         String sport = array[count][2];

         for(int x = 1;x<rep;x++)
         {
            if(!array[countTwo][2].equals(null) && array[countTwo][2].equals(array[count][2]))
               {
               flag = true;
               x = 28;
               }

            else
               {
               flag = false;
               }

            countTwo ++;
         }


         countTwo --;

         if(flag == true)
            {
            System.out.println("I know "+array[countTwo][2]+". It is "+array[countTwo][3]+". My friend "+array[countTwo][1]+" knows it");
            }

         if(flag == false)
            {
            System.out.println("I don't know "+array[count][2]+". I only know robot boxing. Robots hit each other until one malfunctions. What is this alien sport you speak of?");
            array[count][3] = scanSport.nextLine ();
            }

         System.out.println("Go again? Type no to leave me :(");
         leaveQ = leave.nextLine ();

         rep ++;

         count ++;

         if(leaveQ.equals("no"));
            {
            simpleAI2.Save(array);
            }

      }while (!leaveQ.equals("no"));

   }



   public static void Save(String [][] array){

      try {
         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("arrayData.txt"));

         for(int x=0; x<array.length; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<array[x].length; y++){
               writer.write(String.valueOf(array[x][y]));
            }
            writer.println(); 
         }

         writer.flush();  
         writer.close();        



      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
         {      
         e.printStackTrace();
         }


   }

   public static void getArrayData(String [][] array){


      try {
         Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("arrayData.txt"));

         System.out.println(array.length);

         for(int i=0; i<array.length;  i++)
         {
            for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++)
            {
              System.out.println("Test 1");
              System.out.println(array[i][j]);

              if ( ! scan2.hasNext() )  //if there's nothing left to read
                  return; 

               array[i][j]=scan2.next(); 

            }  
         }


      } 

      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
         { 
         System.out.println("Test 2");
         e.printStackTrace(); 
         }    

   }
}
```

Comment: how are you calling `getArrayData`? What array do you pass to this method?

Comment: @almasshaikh simpleAI2.getArrayData(array);

Comment: @almasshaikh simpleAI2 is the name of my class

Comment: what's the content of array. Can you post code in your question so we could help?

Comment: @almasshaikh The content changes. I will post the full code

Comment: @almasshaikh I have added the full code

Comment: You are printing the value before you set it. Move ` System.out.println(array[i][j]);` at the end of the second loop.

Comment: @titus Okay but the printing is just as a test. It doesn't remove from the fact that the program doesn't work

Comment: whats in your txt file?

Comment: You should add a space between each value that you write `writer.write(String.valueOf(array[x][y]) + " ");`

Comment: @almasshaikh It depends on what happens during the program/ what someone enters when it runs. An example is if the user enters name as Tom. Favourite sport as Football. And what it is as kick balls then this is the text file:

Comment: @almasshaikh  This is it: nullTomFootballkick balls
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnull

Comment: @titus I have but it still isn't working

Comment: There are a lot of things that need to be changed, First off you don't need multiple `Scanners` to get the input from the user, second don't use `equals(null)` to check if a `String` is `null` (use `str == null`), third this loop `for(int x = 1;x<rep;x++)` won't execute any iterations because you initialize `rep` to `1` and you also have some logical mistakes.

Comment: @titus thanks for the help. I am very new to this all. Will fixing these solve the issues?

Comment: @titus Thank you so so much. Changing `x<rep` into `x<=rep` seemed to solve my problem. Thank you. Turns out it wasn't reading from the file that was the issue

Comment: @titus correction. It still doesn't work

Comment: @Titus whatever i type in as the favourite sport it will claim to know it. Is there a way of not flagging it as true if it was what was only just entered?

Comment: You will have to get the sport from the user and then loop through all the sports in the `array` to check if it is already in there. eg: `for(int i = 0;i< array.length;i++){if(array[i][2].equals(sport)){flag = true}}` you will have to do this check before you add the `sport` String into the `array`.

Comment: @titus Oh i see. Thank you. I will attempt to implement this.